# How to perform loop with volley

Tags: java, android, json, android-volley

I have problem with loop. In my opinion this should work, but goes one through the loop. I have to do check availability server and I don't have other ideas.

Server give answer:

> {"exist":true}

```
        do {
        generateNumber = generate();
        getExsistResponse = "http://skidd.herokuapp.com/exist/" + generateNumber;


            final StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, getExsistResponse, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    existObject exist = new Gson().fromJson(response, existObject.class);
                    exist.getExist();
                    String abcd = exist.getExist();
                    Boolean boolean1 = Boolean.valueOf(abcd);

                    if (boolean1) {
                        Log.i("Info", "Pokój: " + abcd);
                        textView.setText("" + boolean1);
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), response, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    } else {
                        textView.setText("" + boolean1);
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), response, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    //When an error
                }
            });
            ConnectionManager.getInstance(this).add(request);
            //Add the request to the RequestQueue.
        }while (boolean1);
```

and here is my existObject class:

```
public class existObject {

@SerializedName("exist")
private String checkexist;

public String getExist() {
    return checkexist;
}
public void getExist(String name) {
    this.checkexist = name;
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logic of this approach is not sound. You have made the assumption that the `do-while` loop checks the value of `boolean1` after each web-service call completes. In reality, what happens is that even before the first web-service call has completed, the `do-while` loop has already moved on to the next iteration of the loop, and `boolean1` is probably still false, because the first web-service call has not yet been completed. So the `do-while` loop breaks.

Realize this: a web-service call is *asynchronous*. You simply cannot predict how much time it will take to complete, and the time required for each web-service call to complete will always vary. Your `do-while` loop, on the other hand, is *synchronous*: it keeps on creating `StringRequest` objects and adding them to the `RequestQueue`, and these requests are not executed immediately, so the value of `boolean1` may or may not have been set correctly for the next iteration of the `do-while` loop.

You need to find another way of making successive network calls such that they are not dependent on each other in this way. If you still want to do it like this and depend on `boolean1`, try this:

- Create an `AsyncTask` and perform an `HttpURLConnection` request (and
  not a Volley `Request`) in its `doInBackground()`, and set the value
  of `boolean1` there.
- If the value of `boolean1` is `true`, then create a new instance of
  the same `AsyncTask` in `onPostExecute()` and call `execute()` to
  start the next web-service call.

Comment: but still I have no idea how to do it

Comment: @Xedi: I have suggested an approach. Do you know how to use `AsyncTask` ? If not then first study some examples of how `AsyncTask` works and how to make web service calls with it

Comment: thanks, now i know what i have to do. Thanks for help.